# What did I do wrong? I got $\nabla\cdot \vec A \neq div \vec A $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, differentiation, vector-fields

**We know**, that in orthogonal Curvilinear coordinate system:

> $$ \nabla =\sum_{i=1} ^{3}{\hat{e_i} \over h_i}{\partial \over\partial u_i} $$

Let
$$\vec A=\sum_{i=1} ^{3} A_i  \hat e_i$$
Now
$$ \nabla .\vec A=\sum_{i=1} ^{3} \sum_{j=1} ^{3}{\hat{e_i \over h_i}}{\partial \over\partial u_i}.(A_j \hat e_j)\\\\=\sum_{i=1} ^{3} \sum_{j=1} ^{3}{\hat{e_i} .\hat e_j \over h_i}{\partial \over\partial u_i}.(A_j)$$
In orthogonal system 
$$\hat e_i. \hat e_i=1 \: and \:\hat e_i. \hat e_j=0 , i\neq j$$
So
$$\nabla .\vec A=\sum_{i=1} ^{3}{1\over h_i}{\partial A_i\over\partial u_i} $$ 
But we know
$$div .\vec A={1\over h}\sum_{i=1} ^{3}{\partial {A_i h\over h_i}\over\partial u_i} $$

where $ h = h_1.h_2.h_3$

So where did I mistake?

---

I think my doubt is related to this query:

*In Cartesian*

Let $f(x,y,z)$, now is
$${\partial (f \hat i)\over\partial x}=\hat i {\partial f\over\partial x} $$

Answer (score 3):

The fourth equation line doesn't follow from the third. If you write the arguments of the objects involved, you will realize the basis vectors themselves in general will also depend on the "old" coordinates, so 
$$ \hat{e}_i = \hat{e}_i(u_j)$$
meaning the chain rule must be used and you get:
$$\nabla\cdot\vec{A}=\sum_{i,j=1}^3\frac{\hat{e}_i}{h_i}\left(\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial u_i}\hat{e}_j + A_j\frac{\partial\hat{e}_j}{\partial u_i}\right)$$

The last term above is what is new. A canonical example of this is the case of polar coordinates in 2D (same thing holds for spherical or cylindrical coordinates in 3D):
$$\hat{r} = \cos\theta \hat{i} + \sin\theta\hat{j}$$
so that
$$\frac{\partial\hat{r}}{\partial\theta} = -\sin\theta\hat{i} +\cos\theta\hat{j} = \hat{\theta} $$

Comment: So does ${\partial \hat i\over\partial x}$ and ${\partial \hat i\over\partial y}$ makes sense .